# Tableau: store a dimension across 2 different views

Tags: filtering, tableau-api

I have two views within one dashboard. In view 1, the user selects one or multiple brandnames from a filter. Each brand belongs to a certain sector, which is also a dimension. What I need is, that the second view only shows those sectors that belong to the selected brands, but in this view the filter of the brand name cannot be used! This is because the second view shows the same measure, but from a higher aggregation level (countrylevel instead of brandlevel).

So I would like to 'store' the associated sector from view 1 separate from the brandname, so that I can re-use it in the second view.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your second view you want to pass `Brand`, which you say is the grain of first view.

So to achieve that you must put `Brand` in the `level of detail` of the second sheet.

Then you should `create action filter` with 1st view as `source` and second view as `target`.

Pass `Brand` as the value from 1st to second.

If you want quick filter, then both the view should be from the same data source. Apply Brand filter to all sheets even if the aggregation level is high it would filter the view.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to use brand in the second view at all. Instead I want to use the level of country for that view, but the sectors associated with the brands from the first view should remain.... Or am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: Add brand in the level of detail section of the second view.

Comment: Cannot you put brand as quick filter and apply to all sheets. This should be doable.

Comment: Else for more clarification please share a public link of your work. I am getting confused.

Comment: Allright, I did that, and added the filter. But, now the correct sectors only show when I select the brand in view 1 by clicking. I would like the sectors to be filtered by default, so upon selecting from the brand filter.

Comment: Yeah it is confusing, I understand. I'll try to create a link